# LyX Heading interfering

Tags: sectioning, lyx

How can I make a header like in Img.1 in **LyX**, I tried adding it like in Img.2 and what I get is in Img.3, as you can see it is interfering with the text.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Probably the default value of `\headheight` is too small.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks man you are a life saver, It is perfect now , 
Sorry for asking for more , but Do you know how can I add a line in footer like the one in Header ?

Comment: As far as I know, there are only  two lengths that you can play with, if necessary: one  is the distance between the bottom of the text area and the footnote line, which is known a `\footskip`. The other  is the distance between the footer line and the bottom of the paper sheet.